# Large strings and len()

Tags: python, string, ascii

This may be a newbie question, but here it goes. I have a large `string` (167572 bytes) with both `ASCII` and non ASCII characters. When I use `len()` on the string I get the wrong `length`. It seems that `len()` doesn't count 0x0A characters. The only way I can get the actual length of the string is with this code:

```
for x in test:  
   totalLen += 1   
for x in test:  
   if x == '\x0a':  
      totalLen += 1  
print totalLen
```

What is wrong with `len()`? Or am I using it wrong?

Comment: When you say actual length, how are you getting that?  I'm hoping you didn't hand count all 167572 bytes. :-)

Comment: Your code counts `'\x0a'` characters twice.

Comment: I write the string to a file and open it in a hex editor, that's how I count the number of characters.

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing encoded byte strings with unicode text. In UTF-8, for example, up to 3 bytes are used to encode any given character, in UTF-16 each character is encoded using *at least* 2 bytes each.

A python string is a series of bytes, to get unicode you'd have to decode the string with an appropriate codec. If your text is encoded using UTF-8, for example, you can decode it with:

```
test = test.decode('utf8')
```

On the other hand, data written to a file is *always* encoded, so a unicode string of length 10 could take up 20 bytes in a file, if written using the UTF-16 codec.

Most likely you are getting confused with such 'wider' characters, not with wether or not your `\n` (ASCII 10) characters are counted correctly.

Please do yourself a favour and read up on Unicode and encodings:

- [Joel on Software: The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that you're expecting it to contain `\r\n`, i.e. ASCII 13 (carriage return) followed by ASCII 10 (line feed), or that you look at the string once it's been written out to a text file, which adds these?

It's hard to be specific since you don't give a lot of detail, i.e. where the string's data comes from.